# facebook comments: no input shown if many comments

Tags: javascript, facebook-comments

I have facebook comments on my site. I noticed that when there are 10 comments or above, the plugin doesn't show the comment input box by default (like it does when there are few comments). if a user wants to comment he has to click on "add a comment" link at the top.

I was wondering, is there any way to make the plugin display the comment input no matter what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the settings built into comments box to keep the composer shown.

info on enabling admin/moderator settings https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

[image]